# Angular JS 1 : multiple-date-picker time change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and trying to implement multi date time picker functionlity with one check box .

I am using multiple-date-picker

[multiple-date-picker](https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker)

[image]
and here I am trying to change the time of the date I have picked and want the two values(date with changes time and the check box value) in one new array

right now when I am trying to iterate the array I am getting and pushing the array value to the new array but nothing is working

below is the code

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">              
            <multiple-date-picker ng-model="myArrayOfDates"></multiple-date-picker>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="form-group booking-groups" ng-repeat="m in myArrayOfDates">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">

            <label>{{m| cmdate:'EEEE, d MMM yy' }} &nbsp; Time</label>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="input-time" width="50%">
                <div uib-timepicker ng-model="myArrayofTimes" ng-init="LoadTimes(m)" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" required></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div >
                <div class="input-time" width="50%">
                <label>Allow Multiround Booking</label>
                <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
        $scope.myArrayOfDates = [];

        $scope.myArrayofTimes = [];

        $scope.checkboxModel = [{}];

        $scope.myFinalArray=[];

        $scope.LoadTimes = function (datentime) {

            alert(datentime);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myArrayOfDates.length; i++) {

                alert($scope.myArrayOfDates.length);
                alert($scope.myArrayofTimes.length);
                $scope.myArrayofTimes[i] = $scope.myArrayofDates[i];
                $scope.myArrayofTimes[i] = datentime;
            }

        }
```

Please advice.

Comment: It is unclear from your question what exactly you want to do ? Can you reword your question ?

Comment: A working fiddle/plunker may help us addressing your problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but please see below findings.

Just check this for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myArrayOfDates.length; i++) {

                alert($scope.myArrayOfDates.length);
                alert($scope.myArrayofTimes.length);
                $scope.myArrayofTimes[i] = $scope.myArrayofDates[i];
                $scope.myArrayofTimes[i] = datentime;  //Something is wrong with this
            }
```

You are first assigning value to $scope.myArrayofTimes[i]. And on the next step again overriding this value with datentime.